# Why objective-C is selected as platform for Cocoa why not C, C++?

Tags: objective-c

Why Objective-C is chosen as language for cocoa or cocoa touch, why not other? What are main usages in Objective-C that are not in other languages.

How I can Convince the interviewer about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason is that Cocoa is descended from NeXTStep, which was written in Objective-C back before C++ had the STL (IIRC it didn't even have useful templates back then; I recall `g++` having big warnings in its template implementation into the early 90s).  Also, I gather Jobs & co. preferred the Smalltalk-like OO of Objective C.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for response, but can you tell me little bit more clearly. how can I convince to interviewer that Objective-C is best than any other for developing ios applicaitons and mac os x applications.

Comment: @Madan Mohan - By going the, This is what the platform is written with / in and what is best supported by both the platform and community of developers for iOS and OS X

Comment: @Madan: *That* is a different question, and others here have already addressed it:  since it's the native language of Cocoa, using it introduces the fewest complications.  If you use C++ then you have to worry about different object and class behavior in C++ vs. Objective-C, among other things; if you use C, you're going to have some fairly ugly glue to use Objective-C objects.  And XCode will help you along if it's in Objective-C, whereas you're going to have to do many of the things it does for you manually if you use C++.

Answer (score 2):

Cocoa is it self implemented in Object-C. By using that language a developer can more easily leverage the features of the hose system. While C/C++ are valid languages ( because of Objective-C background in them ) the interface between C/C++ and Cocoa ( because it's Objective-C ) is harder than if you were to just stick with Objective-C.

See more on this from [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/cocoa.html).

Answer (score 0):

First, I think any language with GC is far more productive than any language without.  Especially when programming in the large across many different teams, developers and frameworks, other techniques like reference counting are flawed and lead to code bloat.  Many years ago there was a formal study that showed that the theoretical best performance of Generational Garbage Collection was about 4% of cpu usage.  The theoretical best using reference counting was just under 10%.

The second thing to look at is how confining the language chosen is and how easy it is to blend with other C / C++ code.  Many languages, such as Java, pretty much limit you to a single paradigm.  Objective C is set of OO extensions on top of C.  It has a great deal of flexibility as a result.  In Objective C 2.0 and later, new features such as properties and blocks have also been added.

All the above said there are things I don't like about Objective C.  It is more verbose than I like in a programming language and does not provide sufficient capabilities to do much meta-programming.  I really am not happy that it still does not have namespaces.  I know some of the reasons used to explain this lack but I do not find them at all sufficient.  A flat class and method/selector namespace is not excusable in the 21st century.

What I really want is for MacRuby to take off and be implemented very very efficiently.  A return of Dylan would also be very greatly appreciated.  :)